# Sharing Bytearray in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-bytearray

I have two functions.
One variable bytearray type - data.

First function – Reads a file and adds bytes to ‘data’, second takes and deletes these bytes from ‘data’. Those functions should work at the same time, so I use multiprocessing, and is variable shared the like Value.
But, typecode_or_type of Value doesn’t contain bytearray type.

Okay, I started looking on stackoverflow, and found few approaches to use:

- Proxy
- Memory management (SharedMemory)
- Numpy
- Maybe some ways that were just scrolled)
  A lot of information and I got confused.
  What approach I should explored further and use?

THX!

```
def reader(stream):
    for b in s3_obj._raw_stream:
        stream.extend(b)
        print('Add bytes to stream')

def writer(stream):
    while True:
        if len(stream) >= BUFFER_SIZE:
            process.stdin.write(stream[:1024])
            del stream[:1024]
            print('Dump bytes to pipe')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stream = bytearray()
    data = Value('????', stream)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='p1', target=reader, args=(data, ))
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='p', target=writer, args=(data, ))
    p1.start()
    p.start()
```

Comment: If this is just a simple example, okay. But if this is the actual code, there is no reason to do multiprocessing.

Comment: So why isn't multithreading an option for you here? This seems to be an example of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why don't you just tell us what you are trying to accomplish instead of asking how to get a solution you have chosen to work?

Comment: You may have luck searching "python multiprocessing circular buffer" or "python multiprocessing ring buffer".

Comment: @Booboo, Okay, maybe. I have video in S3 bucket storage, I can receive it from storage apart by bytes like raw_stream. I want to receive and convert it simultaneously.

Comment: @Андрей And `process.stdin` is a pipe created with `subprocess.Popen` (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? It seems to me that `reader` can be reading chunks from your S3 bucket storage and putting the chunks on a `queue.Queue` instance which are gotten by the `writer` thread to pipe it to the translation process. If chunks can be retrieved faster than they can be translated, then but a size limit on the queue. This will cause `reader` to block but you will be achieving processing overlap.